# How to use a function to set column classes for data frames with similar structures?

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames that have the same or similar columns. How do I set variable classes for each using a function rather than having to change each name manually?

```
library(lubridate)

color <- c("red", "blue", "green")
weight <- c("10","5","10")
launch_date <- c("2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-10-02")
df <- data.frame(color, weight, launch_date)

df$color <- as.character(df$color)
df$weight <- as.numeric(df$weight)
df$launch_date <- ymd(df$launch_date)
```

This gets me the result I want, but for example similar dataframes, df2 and df3 I'd like to be able to use a function something like:

```
class_set_fun <- function(x){
 x$color <- as.character(x$color)
 x$weight <- as.numeric(x$weight)
 x$launch_date <- ymd(x$launch_date)
}

class_set_fun(df2)
```

But obviously in this example I run into problems then assigning the name of the variable.

I'd like to avoid having to type in the name of the data frame more than once preferably assigning the function argument as a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readr::type_convert` can do that:

```r
df <- data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                 weight = c("10","5","10"),
                 launch_date = c("2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-10-02"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- readr::type_convert(df)

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ color      : chr  "red" "blue" "green"
#>  $ weight     : int  10 5 10
#>  $ launch_date: Date, format: "2017-10-01" "2017-11-01" ...
```

`utils::type.convert` exists too, but it only works on single vectors, and won't handle dates and datetimes.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure this helps me be able to change all the classes in a function while only typing the data frame name once.

Comment: It _is_ your function. It automatically figures out column types. If you want to set them manually, set its `col_types` parameter.

Comment: I've edited my original question to be more specific about only wanting to type in the name of the df once.

Comment: With `readr::type_convert()` you are only typing the name of the dataset once. I'm struggling to understand why `type_convert` isn't what you need here.

Comment: Very possible I'm misunderstanding, but if I have two df's, df1 and df2, don't I need to type: df1 <- readr::type_convert(df1) & df2 <- readr::type_convert(df2) ?

Comment: It has to be called once per data frame, though it can be iterated over a list of data frames. These issues can (and really should) be taken care of when importing data, as well. What you want is apparently really unclear; you should update your question with the desired output for a reproducible example.